# Cannot install the Azure Az PowerShell module on linux

Tags: azure, powershell

I would like to install the Azure Az PowerShell module on Linux following the instructions from the page [Install the Azure Az PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-7.1.0). If I change to a non-root user, and execute the command:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

I get

```
Install-PackageProvider: Unhandled Exception - Message:'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.FilesystemExtensions' threw an exception.'
Name:'TypeInitializationException' Stack Trace:'   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.FilesystemExtensions.MakeSafeFileName(String input) 
...
```

The

```
PS /root> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      2      1    

PS /home/user> $env:PSModulePath
/home/user/.local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules:/opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules
```

At first sight it looks to me as if there would be a permission problem, but I cannot find the root couse. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to install Az Powershell module with sudo?

Comment: This non-root user does not have sudo permissions. I would avoid sudo if possible due to security concerns.

Comment: Did you try the workaround?
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGetv2/issues/516#issuecomment-846102380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by ownership of /tmp/Microsoft.PackageManagement. Only root and the nonroot user who created it were able to install modules.

Deleting this directory mitigates the issue, but, of course, only for the user who creates it.

https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/400